# Math game problem, not able to understand why the solution works?

Tags: programming, modular-arithmetic

Players A and B

**Rules of the game:**

- The game is played with two piles of matches. Initially, the first
  pile contains N matches and the second one contains M matches.
- The players alternate turns; A plays first.
- On each turn, the current player must choose one pile and remove a
  positive number of matches (not exceeding the current number of
  matches on that pile) from it.
- It is only allowed to remove X matches from a pile if the number of
  matches in the other pile divides X.
- The player that takes the last match from any pile wins.

The solution i have thought for this problem is:

```
if n % m == 0 or m % n== 0 then player A will win
else we will find the reminder and quotient and count the moves

if quotient is > 1: and move is Odd then player A wins

                 2: move is even then player B wins

else swap the larger pile and smaller pile and repeater the above steps
```

Comment: This doesn’t look like it pertains to Mathematica the software from Wolfram Research. Did you post on the wrong site?

Comment: I am confused by the way you have used the word "divides". Suppose I am taking a number $n$ of matches from pile $B$, do you mean I can only do this if $n=ra$ where $r$ is an integer and $a$ is the number of matches in pile $a$ (so if $n$ is a multiple of $a$, which is what you have written). Or do you mean to say that you must have $a=rn$ with $n$ a factor of $a$? And are you allowing $r=0$?

Comment: @MarkBennet why are you confused about divides versus is divisible by ?

Comment: Who ever will got to zero first will win the game for example. I have 1 1 then A will win if I have 155 47 then A will win if I have 6 4 then B will win.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Well as phrased you only seem to be able to take matches from the larger pile (or both if they are equal), yet this is not mentioned as a feature.

Comment: Actually yes that’s the case actually both of the players needs to play optimal moves so that they can win you got that right we will have to choose from the larger pile first then 2nd larger and so on if both are equal then it’s just one move.  And A will win